# Unit testing method that creates objects, trouble asserting

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, assert

I have a method that takes an XML string and parses it, returning an `IEnumerable<Invoice>`. The following is the definition of the classes being used. Note that an `Invoice` contains `InvoiceItem`s:

```
public class Invoice
{
    public const string XmlName = "invoice";

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public DateTime timestamp { get; set; }
    public bool paid { get; set; }
    public IList<InvoiceItem> items { get; set; }

    public Invoice() { this.items = new List<InvoiceItem>(); }

    public decimal getTotal()
    {
        if (items == null)
            return 0;

        decimal total = 0;

        foreach (InvoiceItem item in this.items)
            total += item.amount;

        return total;
    }
}

public class InvoiceItem
{
    public const string XmlName = "item";

    public string description { get; set; }
    public decimal amount { get; set; }
}
```

When unit testing the method with NUnit, something strange is going on with the boolean values for `paid`. Note that I have tested the method in .NET Fiddle, and it returns all the objects it should. So it appears as though something is wrong with the following test (partial code):

```
[Test]
public void readXml_Test()
{
    // arrange

    // xml stuff...

    // expected objects
    InvoiceItem item1 = new InvoiceItem { description = "item 1 in invoice 1", amount = 50 };
    InvoiceItem item2 = new InvoiceItem { description = "item 2 in invoice 1", amount = 50 };
    Invoice invoice1 = new Invoice
    {
        id = 1,
        title = "Aug 2020",
        timestamp = DateTime.ParseExact("16/08/2020 09:01:29 AM", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
        paid = true,
        items = new List<InvoiceItem>() { item1, item2 }
     };
     InvoiceItem item3 = new InvoiceItem { description = "item in invoice 2", amount = 100 };
     Invoice invoice2 = new Invoice
     {
         id = 2,
         title = "Sep 2020",
         timestamp = DateTime.ParseExact("16/08/2020 09:01:29 AM", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
         paid = true,
         items = new List<InvoiceItem> { item3 }
      };

    // act
    List<Invoice> actual = xml.readXml().ToList(); // readXml() is the method under test.

    // assert
    Assert.That(actual.Contains(invoice1));
    Assert.That(actual.Contains(invoice2));
}
```

As mentioned before, I have tested this in .NET fiddle, and the resulting objects all have correct property values. However, the above test yields:

```
Message: Expected: True
 But was: False
```

There is no mention of any exception. Since I know the method under test works, it seems to be a problem with this test. How can I fix it to make it pass?

Comment: `actual.Contains(invoice1)` searches for invoice1 by equality. Since you do not override Equals(), this means that the exact same instance must be in the list which seems unlikely

Comment: @KlausGutter I was starting to think that was the case. If I want to check if `actual` contains the objects as defined in the "arrange" part of the test, how could I go about it, if I don't want to override `Equals()`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51834138/34092 `PropertyCompare` is a reasonably simple way to easily build `Equals` etc.

Comment: `Assert.That(actual.Any(item => item.Id == invoice1.Id))` would be an option